# 1 QuerySnapshot returning null in Flutter web app but gives result in the Android console

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

I am having an issue where the QuerySnashot from the firestore giving correct value when printing in the android console but returns a null when building it on the flutter web app. Can someone please assist on what I am doing wrong?
Here is the function giving me the correct print:

```
countpassengers() async {
    String collection = "users";
    QuerySnapshot _myDoc = await firebaseFiretore.collection(collection).get();
    List<DocumentSnapshot> _myDocCount = _myDoc.docs;
    print("Number of Users: :::::::::::::");
    print(_myDocCount.length);  // Count of Documen
    totalusers = _myDocCount.length.toString() ;//ts in Collection
    print (totalusers.toString());
    return totalusers ;
}
```

and here is how I am calling it (returning null) somehow

```
InfoCard(
         title: "Number of Passengers",
         value: totalusers.toString(),//"3",
         onTap: () {},
         topColor: Colors.orange,
),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are returning the output from a function to **State** you need to rebuild the state by calling **setState** function.

By calling setState, the whole StatefulWidget knows something is updated and rebuild the state with new data. So insert setState after calling your Firestore function in the class. It could be inside a function or inside `onTap: (){}`.

If you call that function inside your `onTap: (){}`, don't forget to add async like that: `onTap: () async{}` and `await` your returning data.

Comment: Thanks you so much this works like a charm. I added SetState and it solved my 2  weeks struggle. Thank you so much

Comment: @RogerantTshibangu you are welcome. Please do your research about how to use setState and when. It is not a good way to call setState everytime when you have new update, data. It will slow down your application if you use it too much. You can consider to use state management library such as BLoC or Provider if your app is complex and big.

Comment: Thank You @ZahidTekbas.  I will have a look.